# mysql.connector/Python "Invalid utf8mb4 character string" when inserting into a BINARY column

Tags: python, mysql, charset

I need your help, this is driving me crazy.

I need to insert a Python SHA hash into a BINARY column and I can't get past the ***mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1300: Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'E9A834'*** error.

I'm using:

- Python 3.8.5
- mysql-connector-python==8.0.25
- MySQL 8.0.24 'MySQL Community Server - GPL'

```
  tagscad = ' '.join(sorted([cad.lower() for cad in curcripto['tags']]))
  idtags = hashlib.sha256(tagscad.encode('utf-8')).digest()

  try:
    cursor.execute("insert into histotags "
                    "(hashix,tags) values (%s,%s)", (idtags,tagscad))

  except mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError as err:
    print(f"tags: {tagscad}")
    raise
  except mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError as err:
    print(f"tags: {tagscad}")
    raise
```

My table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `histotags` (
  `hashix` binary(32) NOT NULL,
  `verifix` binary(32) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (unhex(sha2(`tags`,256))) STORED,
  `tags` varchar(2048) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`hashix`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

I have also tried with the default table collation for MySQL 8.0.24, utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci and also instantiating the cursor object with raw=True, the error is the same: it complains about inserting an invalid utf8mb4 character string (idtags is a b prefixed string starting with the E9 A8 34 sequence) into the binary column hashix. Seems to me the b'string' gets converted somewhere to a regular string but nevertheless... what could I be doing wrong here, is there any way arount it?